# Python Behave feature file warnings

Tags: python, pycharm, python-behave

I am not new to web automation with selenium but I am very new to python I am trying to create my own dynamic structure. With a little bit effort I can do  the BE coding with python but when it comes to behave feature file I don't get the problem I am having. Basically my code works fine evet step that I have is implemented and it runs but when I am on PyCharm ide and open feature file my feature file looks like this
[feature file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s1wB.png)

I couldn't find a solution online can anyone help me with this so steps can look normal and I can navigate to them by clicking ctrl + LMC

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The BDD feature is only available in Pycharm professional and not in community version.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/bdd-frameworks.html

That's the reason you are unable to navigate to steps and the code is getting highlighted.

If you like, you can use Visual Studio Code IDE, and can install any gherkin plugin to get through this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that PyCharm does not find the step definition.

Could you attach the directory tree of your project? It's possible that you don't follow Behave standards and that's why PyCharm is not able to find where the steps are defined.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32823350)